# How can we monitor failure in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

Everyone,
can anyone tell me how to monitor failure in jquery ajax call. We have 'success:' for success but is there is anyway to detect failure event.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is `error` callback for that:

```
$.ajax({ 
 ........,
 ........,
 success: function(){alert('success !');},
 error:function(){alert('failed!');},
});
```

---

[See the DOCS for more information :)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the 'error' callback.